# Is there a database of Dirichlet Series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request

I didn't think this would be difficult to find given how old and allegedly well-researched the subject is, but I haven't been able to find a list of explicitly known Dirichlet Series. There is the simple case being equivalent to The Riemann zeta function, but it appears no one has been able to compile more than that. 
For instance, it should contain entries such as $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^s} = \ldots$ , $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^s} = \ldots$ , $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\log(n)}{n^s}\ldots$ , $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{\cot(\pi n)}{n^s} =\ldots$  and so on.

Comment: https://www.lmfdb.org/

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain the right question. You see how this site http://people.math.sc.edu/girardi/m142/handouts/10sTaylorPolySeries.pdf has an explicit, compact, straightforward list of Taylor series? That is what is missing for Dirchlet series. It might also be described as a list of Zeta functions or a list of L-functions.

Comment: Like here wikipedia talks about it, but unlike what it typically is expected to have, it doesn't really have a list of the different results for different Dirchlet characters https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_L-function

Comment: That list of power series has 6 examples.  Those are the few standard power series taught in calculus courses.  There are infinitely many important Dirichlet series, so the idea of a tidy list of them for study is missing the point.  There are Dedekind zeta-functions, Hasse--Weil zeta-functions, Dirichlet $L$-functions, Artin $L$-functions, $L$-functions of modular forms, and so on. The website I mentioned does list initial coefficients $a_n$ of the examples it has, and you can request a longer list of coefficients. So again, the site lmfdb.org does what you want.

Comment: A Dirichlet series is determined by its coefficients, so you might as well be asking for lists of interesting coefficients of Dirichlet series.  Something you might not realize based on the examples you gave is that many important Dirichlet series do *not* have nice rules for the coefficients $a_n$ as explicit functions of $n$ (e.g., coefficients for the Dirichlet series of many Artin $L$-functions or $L$-functions of cusp forms).

Comment: @KCd There are infinitely many important Taylor series, but that obviously hasn't stopped people from compiling lists of Taylor series, which can also be represented as series of coefficients, so your point seems moot. If imfdb does have this list, can you link to it? I already looked at the dirichlet characters page and it does not have such a list.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/missouri-journal-of-mathematical-sciences/volume-20/issue-1/A-Catalog-of-Interesting-Dirichlet-Series/10.35834/mjms/1316032830.full) might approach what you are looking for: "A Catalog of Interesting Dirichlet Series" by H. W. Gould and Temba Shonhiwa.